# Initialization of Jmol applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet, localhost

I have a java applet that I need to embed in a web page. And I have a local host set up to view the web page. When I open the web page from the server using localhost:8080 , the applet gives an error "not initialized".
But if I open the web page on my browser the applet loads just fine.
Here is the code that I am using for the applet:

```html
<form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
jmolInitialize("/home/mahnoor/Desktop/fridb/Jmol/",window.location.protocol=="file:");
jmolSetCallback("UseCommandThread","true");
jmolApplet(200, "load /home/mahnoor/Desktop/fridb/database/bnp/POSCAR.xyz" , "one");
    </script>
  </form>
```

Jmol is a 3D molecular viewer program that using javascript and here is a more detailed explanation for Jmol http://jmol.sourceforge.net/.
POSCAR.xyz in the code above is the file with molecular structure that needs to be loaded in the web page. And I am willing to provide the contents of this file if it is helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: I am using Linux, and the Firefox browser supports applets according to java.com. Can you please elaborate on how I can configure java console on Linux mint?

Comment: *"Can you please elaborate on how I can configure java console on Linux mint?"*  The script does not support it?

Comment: In the console 'favicon.ico' has a 404 error, do I have to provide that?     "Get /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 742 and I have not provided that, can this be the reason that the applet is not loading?Because java console is figured to show applets. Or do you think that the applet behaving this way could be a security issue?

Comment: *"In the console 'favicon.ico' has a 404 error"*  I am almost certain you are referring to a web or JS console that is not the same as the one to which I am referring (and linked).  What OS is this?  What browser?

Comment: I am using Firefox, on Ubuntu (64bit). And yes I am referring to web console.

Comment: Well, in case it is not (bleedingly) obvious, that is ***not*** the console I am referring to.  If you cannot produce the right console, our chances of solving this approach 0%.  And to be clear, trying to create a) an applet, using b) a 3rd party API, is an advanced topic.  You should avoid this sort of stuff for a (long) while.